# DB2 Native Library can't find libraries

Tags: db2

I have an application that depends on loading a db2 driver. I was getting weird errors that the db2jcct2.dll wasn't being loaded, so I made sure to add it to my lib path per: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21419978 and I also made sure it was added to java.library.path at program startup. After doing that I get the following error/stack trace.

```
com.ibm.db2.jcc.c.SqlException: Failure in loading T2 native library db2jcct2, reason: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\SQLLIB\BIN\db2jcct2.dll: Can't find dependent libraries
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t2.a.a(a.java:31)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t2.T2Configuration.<clinit>(T2Configuration.java:84)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t2.a.a(a.java:31)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver.connect(DB2Driver.java:174)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t2.T2Configuration.<clinit>(T2Configuration.java:84)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver.connect(DB2Driver.java:174)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:571)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:571)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:215)
```

Comment: If there's ANY more information you need or want just let me know!

Comment: So, does the file `C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\SQLLIB\BIN\db2jcct2.dll` exist? Does the user running the application have appropriate permissions?

Comment: Yes it exists, and the user has appropriate permissions. I tried using dependency walker (program) to see what this dll is attempting to load, but it didn't tell me anything.

Comment: What DB2 client type and version do you have installed, and what is the operating system version?

Comment: You have a 32-bit DB2 client installed on 64-bit Windows;  are you running a 32-bit or 64-bit JVM?  My suspicion is that you would need a 32-bit JVM to be able to load the 32-bit native client libraries...

Comment: Also, is there a reason why you are using the Type 2 driver, instead of using the java-only Type 4 driver?  The Type-4 driver doesn't depend on the native client.

Comment: mustaccio: 9.7 java connector, the OS is windows 7 64-bit.

@Ian Bjorhovde 32-bit JVM as far as I know, I checked that when I came across the IBM support articles for the native drivers. 

The reason I'm using the Type 2 driver is because I'm supporting some legacy code that was written long before I came to my current company. Maybe I'll try switching it over to the Type-4 Driver.

Comment: I don't know what "java connector" is. There are _IBM Data Server Client_, _IBM Data Server Runtime Client_, _IBM Data Server Driver Packgage_ etc. -- [see here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24034634) The technote you've mentioned states that the bitness of your OS must match the bitness of the client and JVM for type 2 connectivity, which apparently is not the case. It's not enough to install the JDBC driver package for type 2 connectivity -- you must install at least the runtime client.

Comment: @ripit, did you find a final solution?